# How to get data from web assembly to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c, web-audio-api, webassembly, pcm

I have build the libopus library using emscripten compiler by writing wrapper over it and exposed some API to JavaScript which will get decoded audio PCM data.
Now I am able to send data to web assembly from JavaScript to decode it but don't have any idea how to get from Module memory in JavaScript.
Following wrapper I have written over libopus.

```
   extern "C" {
   int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE decode_opus(void * dec, unsigned char const * data, size_t datasz)
   {
     /* Decode the data. In this example, frame_size will be constant because
        the encoder is using a constant frame size. However, that may not
        be the case for all encoders, so the decoder must always check
        the frame size returned. */

        OpusDecoder *decoder=(OpusDecoder *)dec;
        opus_int16 out[MAX_FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS];
        int frame_size,i;
        frame_size = opus_decode(decoder, data, datasz, out, MAX_FRAME_SIZE, 0);
        if (frame_size<0)
        { 
          //fprintf(stderr, "decoder failed: %s\n", opus_strerror(frame_size));
          emscripten_log(EM_LOG_CONSOLE, "decoder failed: %s\n", opus_strerror(frame_size));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
       unsigned char pcm_bytes[MAX_FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS*2];

       /* Convert to little-endian ordering. */
      for(i=0;i<CHANNELS*frame_size;i++)
      {
             pcm_bytes[2*i]=out[i]&0xFF;
             pcm_bytes[2*i+1]=(out[i]>>8)&0xFF;
      }
      /* Write the decoded audio to file. 
        fwrite(pcm_bytes, sizeof(short), frame_size*CHANNELS, fout);
     */

     //auto arrayPtr = &pcm_bytes[0];
      frame_size=frame_size*CHANNELS;
      EM_ASM_({
        frame_opusCallback($0, $1);
      },&pcm_bytes[0],frame_size
     );
   }
  }
```

In JavaScript I am getting decoded data in callback frame_opusCallback first parameter `$0` contains decoded data and second $1 parameter contains size of decoded data.
I have implemented following callback in JavaScript.

```
 function frame_opusCallback(a,b) {   
   console.log("Getting callback from liobopus"+b);   
   var arrayData = [];      
   for (let v=0; v < b; v++) {         
      arrayData.push(Module.HEAPF32[a/Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT+v])     
   }      
 }
```

**Update**

Now I have got some knowledge about `Module` and how it works, so I have updated my JavaScript handler to get the value from `Module` memory has fallows.

```
    function convertBlock(incomingData) { // incoming data is a UInt8Array
    var i, l = incomingData.length;
    var outputData = new Float32Array(incomingData.length);
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    outputData[i] = (incomingData[i] - 128) / 128.0;
    }
    return outputData;
    }

    function frame_opusCallback(a,b)
    {
       //console.log("Getting callback from liobopus"+b);

        var incomingData= new Uint8Array(Module.HEAP8.buffer, a, b);
        var sampledata = convertBlock(incomingData);
        postMessage({'data':sampledata});
    }
```

After getting the data from callback I wants to play in PCM audio player. But currently it is not playing.

But when I play audio data in PCM player it is not playing.
As per my knowledge to play audio it needs to be in `Float32Array` so I have converted it using `convertBlock` function.
Please let me know where does I making mistake.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `pcm_bytes[0]` is `unsigned char`, but `a` is handled as `float*`. Does `EM_ASM_(..., out, frame_size)` and `Module.HEAP16` make sense?

Comment: @zakki now I have updated the question please check now and let me know whether I am right or not.

Comment: Are these for Ogg Opus files or is Opus audio in another container?

Comment: @Justin opus audio is coming from RTSP stream in packets.